# How to read custom string with C++ from binary recursively

Tags: c++, string, recursion

I've recently been getting in to IO with C++. I am trying to read a string from a binary file stream.

The custom type is saved like this:

The string is prefixed with the length of the string. So hello, would be stored like this: 6Hello\0.

I am basically reading text from a table (in this case a name table) in a binary file. The file header tells me the offset of this table (112 bytes in this case) and the number of names (318).

Using this information I can read the first byte at this offset. This tells me the length of the string (e.g. 6). So I'll start at the next byte and read 5 more to get the full string "Hello". This seems to work fine with the first name at the offset. trying to recursively read the rest provides a lot of garbage really. I've tried using loops and recursive functions but its not working out so well. Not sure what the problem is, so reverted to the original one name retrieval method. Here's the code:

```
int printName(fstream& fileObj, __int8 buff, DWORD offset, int& iteration){
    fileObj.seekg(offset);
    fileObj.read((char*)&buff, sizeof(char));
    int nameSize = (int)buff;

    char* szName = new char[nameSize];
    for(int i=1; i <= nameSize; i++){
        fileObj.seekg(offset+i);
        fileObj.read((char*)&szName[i-1], sizeof(char));
    }
    cout << szName << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea how to iterate through all 318 names without creating dodgy output?
Thanks for taking the time to look through this, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to use recursion to do that? Simple loops will work just fine.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ I tried nesting that inside another loop but the output is not what it should be. Every string after the first one is garbage and random each time. I'm missing something, not sure what

Comment: Well, inspect your code with the debugger to find out what you've been missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overcomplicating a bit - there's no need to seek to the next sequential read.

Removing unused and pointless parameters, I would write this function something like this:

```
void printName(fstream& fileObj, DWORD offset) {
    char size = 0;
    if (fileObj.seekg(offset) && fileObj.read(&size, sizeof(char)))
    {
        char* name = new char[size];
        if (fileObj.read(name, size))
        {
            cout << name << endl;
        }
        delete [] name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a bunch. The reason why I was getting garbage results was that each string was also followed by a 32 bit interger. Basically a bunch of flags. Its all fixed now :D